# How to Disable Multicursor in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I find multiple cursors feature annoying and I am unable to find a way to turn it off permanently (I often start it by mistake).

I tried searching on the internet and in Settings, but I found nothing.

Comment: It's really annoying agreed. I tried to find it in notebook settings to no avail.